# Задача на С++. Минимальный простой делитель

Tags: c++, математика, факторизация, теория-чисел

Дано целое число, не меньшее 2. Выведите его наименьший простой делитель. Вводится целое положительное число N ≤ 2·10<sup>9</sup>. Выведите ответ на задачу.
Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    long long i = 3, n;
    cin >> n;
    if (n % 2 == 0) cout << 2;
    else {
        while (n % i != 0) {
            i += 2;
        }
        cout << i;
    }
}
```

Его проблема в том, что мне пишет: Программа выполнялась слишком долго и была прервана. Я хочу узнать, как это исправить и получается ускорить процесс.

Comment: Если число простое, то вы выполняете N/2 операций взятия остатка, что занимает внушительное время. Проверить число на простоту несложно за O(sqrt(N)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    long long i = 3, n;
    cin >> n;
    if (n % 2 == 0) cout << 2;
    else {
        while(n%i && i*i <= n) {
            i += 2;
        }
        cout << ((n%i) ? n : i);
    }
}
```